# How can I get the column names returned by a dbo function

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I look at a view/table, I can get the column names using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table'
```

Obviously, this will work to show columns for tables; but it does not work for functions. Is there an easy way (besides getting one record from a function, and manually parsing it) to get the column names returned by a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS
```

I'm unsure if this works for inline `TVF`s